# Python - Use pytest to test test methods written in subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, pytest, fixtures

I am a novice to pytest. I have a scenario wherein i wanted to test some test methods written in a subclass.

Assume that the following is my code structure

```
class Superclass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def dummy_print():
        print("This is a dummy function")

class TestSubClass(Superclass):

def test_1_eq_1():
    assert 1 == 1
```

Upon executing the following command

```
py.test -s -v test_filename.py
```

I get the following error messgae:

> cannot collect test class 'Test_Super' because it has a **init** constructor

The same is mentioned in the pytest documentation as well.

Is there a workaround for this?

I need the superclass' `__init__()` method because all my test files would need to inherit from the super class.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple workaround. Split your class hierarchy in two — one for data (with \_\_init\_\_) and one for tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytest is different beast than, say unittests. It [prohibits](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) class hierarchies, which you can see in the warning message.

If you need some pre-initialization steps, do them using [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html):

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def pre_run_initialization():
    # do before test
    yield
    # do after test
```

Comment: Inheritance is no longer mentioned in the [linked doc page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html). I've [been unable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040478/how-to-test-a-class-inherited-methods-in-pytest/46061409#comment79117702_46061409) to find any corroborating information or opinions that class inheritance is prohibited or discouraged. Though, in practice, a marker applied to a class inheriting a superclass will also unintentionally have the marker applied to all other subclasses.