# How to test a class' inherited methods in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

`house.py`:

```
class House:
    def is_habitable(self):
        return True

    def is_on_the_ground(self):
        return True
```

`conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
from house import House


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def house():
    return House()
```

`test_house.py`:

```
class TestHouse:
    def test_habitability(self, house):
        assert house.is_habitable()

    def test_groundedness(self, house):
        assert house.is_on_the_ground()
```

Up to that point, everything is being tested.

Now I add a subclass and override a method in `house.py`:

```
class House:
    def is_habitable(self):
        return True

    def is_on_the_ground(self):
        return True


class TreeHouse(House):
    def is_on_the_ground(self):
        return False
```

I also add a new fixture for that class in `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
from house import House
from house import TreeHouse


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def house():
    return House()


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def tree_house():
    return TreeHouse()
```

I add a new test class for tree house in `test_house.py`:

```
class TestHouse:
    def test_habitability(self, house):
        assert house.is_habitable()

    def test_groundedness(self, house):
        assert house.is_on_the_ground()


class TestTreeHouse:
    def test_groundedness(self, tree_house):
        assert not tree_house.is_on_the_ground()
```

At that point, the code works, but there are cases that are not tested. For example, to be complete, I would need to test again the methods inherited from `House` in `TreeHouse`.

Rewriting the same tests from the `TestHouse` would not be DRY.

How do I test the inherited method of `TreeHouse` (in this case `is_habitable`) without duplicating code?

I would like something like re-testing the `TreeHouse` with the same tests that its super class runs through, but not for the methods / properties that are new or overridden.

After some research I came across contradictory sources. And after digging in the pytest documentation I fail to understand what applies to this scenario.

I am interested in the **pytest** way to do this. Please reference the docs and explain how that applies here.

Comment: your very last line should be `assert not tree_house.is_on_the_ground()`

Comment: thanks for the edit @PaulH

Comment: @PaulH I guess I could also get rid of the `== True` in the other asserts.

Comment: yes. Did `assert not tree_house.is_on_the_ground()` solve your problems? that should take care of things

Comment: @PaulH this specific test was never a problem. The code works. The question is about expanding this code to test inherited methods.

Comment: what is the purpose of testing the inherited methods if you already test them in `TestHouse`?

Comment: Good question @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen :) One reason is to be formal, and make sure the code is not altered by something we could not see coming. And another reason is the use of mixins (multiple inheritance), that can go very wrong. I guess there must be other use cases.

Comment: @Bastian another would be if non overridden methods called overridden ones, sometimes I get tunnel vision when looking at peoples examples ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use the fixture name `house` for all test methods (even if it's testing a `TreeHouse`), and [override its value in each test context](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#overriding-fixtures-on-various-levels):

```
class TestTreeHouse(TestHouse):
    @pytest.fixture
    def house(self, tree_house):
        return tree_house

    def test_groundedness(self, house):
        assert not house.is_on_the_ground()
```

Also note `TestTreeHouse` inherits from `TestHouse`. Since [pytest merely enumerates methods of classes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) (i.e. there is no "registration" done with, say, a `@pytest.test()` decorator), all tests defined in `TestHouse` will be discovered in subclasses of it, without any further intervention.

Comment: I like the answer. On this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44431292/1075374 though, it is said that pytest prohibits class hierarchies, although the link does not explain it. Do you have an opinion on that?

Comment: I tried that and for some reason `self` gets lost in the way. `TestTreeHouse.test_habitability` --> `TypeError: is_habitable() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. Same thing happens with the second test. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you're returning the *class object* `TreeHouse` from the `tree_house` fixture, instead of an instance of the class: `TreeHouse()`

Comment: As for class hierarchies, pytest skips classes with \_\_init__ defined; it doesn't prohibit inheritance. I haven't been able to find record of why that decision was made, but [this comment](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/410#issuecomment-128147735) suggests one reason is because pytest can't supply args to \_\_init__, so defining the method was probably a mistake. The conventional wisdom seems to be "use fixtures", though I haven't found record of that, either :P

Comment: You are so right, I was passing the class instead of an instance. Thanks so much for the research, really appreciated.

Comment: This is a really elegant solution for nested discovery and testing of subclasses / test cases. Could you please provide a link or reference for this - specifically with regards to the scope of the house fixture as it appears in the the conftest.py file and whether it is redefined in the new context under the TestTreeHouse Class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pytest parameterization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) to pass multiple arguments to the same test, in this case, the argument would most likely be the class being tested.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I use parameters in order to repeat tests with different parameters / arguments. But I don't see how that would work in this context. Would you care to expand your answer further than just a link to the docs by clarifying and showing some working code?