# How to test a class hierarchy in pytest?

Tags: python, inheritance, pytest

I've been using pytest for a while and learnt to love parametrization and fixtures. For the first time, I want to test a number of classes with a branched inheritance structure. Naturally, I would like to reuse test cases for child classes. Say I have the following package structure:

```
mock
├── pkg
│   ├── child.py
│   ├── grandchild.py
│   └── parent.py
└── tests
    ├── test_child.py
    ├── test_grandchild.py
    └── test_parent.py
```

As outlined in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040478/how-to-test-a-class-inherited-methods-in-pytest) I can use a fixture to provide an instance of the class being tested. However, when I import a test class from one test module in another it (a) feels like it's not the pytest way and (b) pytest will run all test methods of the imported class plus run them again as part of the inherited test class. Say for example the file `test_child.py` contained the following:

```
from test_parent import TestParent


class TestChild(TestParent):

    def test_foo(self):
        pass

    def test_bar(self):
        pass
```

this causes pytest to run the test methods in `TestParent` once (due to being imported in the module) plus another time as part of `TestChild` (due to its methods being inherited).

So I see two ways: (1) Do not inherit the base test class but just create a fixture so that the current instance is used both for `TestParent` and `TestChild`, essentially:

```
import pytest

from pkg.child import Child
from test_parent import TestParent


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def instance():
    return Child()


class TestChild(object):

    def test_foo(self, instance):
        pass

    def test_bar(self, instance):
        pass
```

(2) The other way I see is to not import any test classes but just create a parametrized fixture in `test_parent.py` that would insert instances of all relevant classes into those test methods. Something like:

```
import pytest

from pkg.parent import Parent
from pkg.child import Child
from pkg.grandchild import GrandChild


@pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=[Parent, Child, GrandChild])
def instance(request):
    return request.param()


class TestParent(object):

    def test_base(self, instance):
        pass
```

Thinking about it, I like option (2) much better since it avoids imports and I could even skip test classes altogether. Is there a better way, though?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original suggestion with `class TestChild(TestParent):` should work fine.  Just avoid importing it under a name which gets collected by pytest.  E.g.:

```
# test_parent.py
class TestParent:

    def test_parent(self):
        assert True
```

and

```
# test_child.py
import test_parent as parent  # renaming not required

class TestChild(parent.TestParent):

    def test_child(self):
        assert True
```

Running this:

```
> pytest -v
======================== test session starts =========================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5rc1, pytest-3.5.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /home/flub/.virtualenvs/a713d56197da3b03/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /tmp/sandbox, inifile:
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                    

test_child.py::TestChild::test_child PASSED                     [ 33%]
test_child.py::TestChild::test_parent <- test_parent.py PASSED  [ 66%]
test_parent.py::TestParent::test_parent PASSED                  [100%]

=================== 3 passed in 0.01 seconds =========================
```

Note that the renaming is not required as `test_` is only treated as a test when a function or method.  But it's nice to do in order to avoid confusion.