# How to go about converting a test-suite from unittest to pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I know that one can run the tests written for unittest directly by pytest. But I want to rewrite them to make use of all that pytest has to offer.
So, I would like to know

1. How to go about doing it manually?
2. If there is an automated tool which can do or at least partially do it.

Comment: There seems to be a [conversion tool](https://github.com/pytest-dev/unittest2pytest), though I haven't tested it. Generally, I would do this incrementally - if you want to change a certain test, convert the related test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to pytest (but not new to xunit). It looks to me like you will spend most of your time refactoring setup and teardown into fixtures. See [four phase test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Four%20Phase%20Test.html).

If you have a class hierarchy to test look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749695/how-to-test-a-class-hierarchy-in-pytest).